# Is it possible to customize the long3col glossaries style?

Tags: glossaries

With the help of existing answers on this site I managed to include a glossary for my document. In the `glossaries` documentation (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) I read about customizing glossaries and in particular about the `long3col` style:

```
 long3col 
 The long3col style is like long but has three columns. The first
 column contains the entry’s name, the second column contains
 the description and the third column contains the number list.
```

My question is the following: is it possible to customize the `long3col` glossaries style such that each term has two corresponding descriptions one for the second column ( i.e. a definition ) and one for the third column ( i.e. an example or formula )? So, 1) is this possible?

And 2) if the customization is possible then what is the best approach to implement this?

This MWE is for convenience only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=altlist]{glossaries}

% \usepackage{glossary-mcols}
% \renewcommand*{\glsmcols}{3}
% \setglossarystyle{mcolindex}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this should be possible. The question is how you want to add the 2nd description or the formula -- as `user1` etc. key?

Comment: Preferably as a custom key, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest way is to reuse the `long3col` style in a new glossary style, say `doubledescriptioncol` and use one of the six user keys `user1`...`user6`.

To get the content of user key `user1` apply the command `\glsuseri` etc, i.e. append the lower case roman number correspending to the key number to the command name `glsuser`.

```
\newglossarystyle{doubledescriptioncol}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the long3col style
% Now change the glossary environment, i.e. the `longtable` wrapper.
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
% This is used as the header of the `longtable`. 
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Formula \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
%The most important command: What is shown in which style:

\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} % link the target
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description   % Enter the description 
&  \glsdisablehyper\glsuseri{##1}  \tabularnewline    % Fetch the user1 key content. 
}
}
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}


\makeglossaries


\newglossarystyle{doubledescriptioncol}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
  \begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
  \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Formula \\
  \hline
  \endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
&  \glsuseri{##1}  \tabularnewline
}
}


\newglossaryentry{Einstein}
{
    name=Einstein,
    description={Great Scientist},
    user1={\ensuremath{E=mc^{2}}}
}

\newglossaryentry{spherevolume}
{
    name={Sphere volume},
    description={Volume of a sphere in 3-D space},
    user1={\ensuremath{V=\frac{4}{3} \pi r^{3}}}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\glsaddall

\clearpage

\setglossarystyle{doubledescriptioncol}
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ndroock1: Please note, that using a real new glossary key might be the better way, but this is a quick way to make it work

Comment: I came across one issue. To get the links working to the glossary I imported the hyperref package. The links work correct but also the values in the formula column appear as links in the pdf document.  In the original long3col this was a ref to a formula number if I am correct. Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: Add `\glsdisablehyper` just before \glsuseri{##1}` -- I've done so in my post